# Remove ActionBar shadow on Android L (API 21)

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm tring to remove the ActionBar Shadow in Android L. On API 14 this code works

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>                                    
</style>
```

But if i put the same code into /values-v21 not works. Any idea on how can i solve? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Android 5.0, Action Bars use an elevation to provide the shadow. You can remove the elevation programmatically via `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0)`

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you can also remove the elevation in the style.xml: <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>